# How to make a non-custom field required

Tags: fields, required

I see that I can make a custom field and have it be a required field, but I already have a standard Industry field, for example, and I don't see any option to make it required.

Comment: Do you mean marking it as required at the API level?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a salesforce standard field required you have couple of declarative approaches.

1. Make it required from the Object's pagelayout
2. You can write some validation rules around that field to your desire!

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to mark a Standard Field at API level, you **cannot** do that (as of today). You can only customize some aspects of Standard Fields on any Object, but you can mark a standard field as required on page layout or use validation rules. Even on Custom object, you will always want to mark a field as required at API level, only when you know that that field will always contain a value in it.

Consider this, Salesforce as a product offers standard objects and fields on them but it will never know how those entities are utilized at an end user implementation. E.g., if by default `Industry` field on `Account` is marked as required at API level, then any Integration which say creates/updates an Account and does not have a value for `Industry` field will always fail.

Some helpful resources on this topic:

- [Customize Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_fields.htm&type=5)
- [What’s the Difference between Standard Fields and Custom Fields?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_differences.htm&type=5)
- [Manage Fields for a Specific Object](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=viewing_fields.htm&type=5)
- [Require Field Input to Ensure Data Quality](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_universally_required_fields.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thing is, you can effectively require it at the "API level" by creating a validation rule.  Not sure why Salesforce restricts you from allowing you to mark it as required on your own individual org.

Comment: Agreed. And that would be desirable, but unfortunately that doesn't exist as of now. This can be a good candidate for an idea on the idea forum.